# Why my google colab is not working for my Google Chrome

Tags: google-colaboratory

Colab is not opening in Chrome, When I try to inspect it, it says:

```
Recording uncaught error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
external_polymer_bin...RC02_.....
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update your Google Chrome version to >=80 and it works perfectly!

Source: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2296 and https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2269

Answer (score 0):

Did you try reloading the page?, I'm quite sure enough it's not a problem with either chrome or colab, may be it's

1. an internet connection problem: so check your internet connection first, or try opening other sites.
2. the notebook you are trying to open is corrupted: try to open a new notebook from colab.

**Edit:**

According to @Benedict, it turned out to be a chrome version issue, you should be able to get it solved by updating chrome.

Comment: Facing the same issue! Not an internet connection problem and notebook isn't corrupted. Works from Mozilla. Tried clearing cookies also, didn't help!

Comment: At the time I saw that problem, I opened colab right away in my chrome and it worked perfectly, may be it's a problem with chrome version then.

Comment: @Benedict are you also using Ubuntu like the one who asked that question?, may be it's a problem with chrome on Ubuntu.

Comment: Yeah, looks like its a Chrome version issue. Got it fixed by updating!